# Can't play video created with OpenCV VideoWriter

Tags: python, opencv

## MWE

```py
import cv2


FPS = 30
KEY_ESC = 27
OUTPUT_FILE = "vid.mp4"

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

codec = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"mp4v") # MPEG-4 http://mp4ra.org/#/codecs
frame_size = cam.read()[1].shape[:2]
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(OUTPUT_FILE, codec, FPS, frame_size)

# record until user exits with ESC
while True:
    success, image = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("window", image)

    video_writer.write(image)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) == KEY_ESC:
        break

cam.release()
video_writer.release()
```

## Problem

Video does not play.

Firefox reports "No video with supported format and MIME type found.".

VLC reports "cannot find any /moov/trak" "No steams found".

Comment: Try to finalize the video by closing the VideoWriter after breaking the loop. Should be .release or .close

Comment: Not the problem here, but added for correctness, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `np.ndarray.shape`, [although not properly documented](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape), returns `(rows, columns)` for a 2d array, which corresponds to `(height, width)`. `VideoWriter(frameSize)` [although not properly documented](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga346f563897249351a34549137c8532a0), seems to expect `(width, height)`.

You can correct this with:

```py
frame_size = tuple(reversed(cam.read()[1].shape[:2]))
```

But, I recommend creating the `VideoWriter` using the `VideoCapture` properties as follows:

```py
output_file = "vid.mp4"
codec = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"mp4v")

fps = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

frame_width = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
frame_height = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
frame_size = (int(frame_width), int(frame_height))

video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, codec, fps, frame_size)
```

---

Sources:
[VideoWriter()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59)
[VideoCapture.get()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aa6480e6972ef4c00d74814ec841a2939)
https://answers.opencv.org/question/66545/problems-with-the-video-writer-in-opencv-300/

Related:
[OpenCV - Video doesn't play after saving in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62146188/opencv-video-doesnt-play-after-saving-in-python)
[OpenCV VideoWriter: Issues with playing video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038980/opencv-videowriter-issues-with-playing-video)

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23089