# generating empty video file with opencv, and I don't want to

Tags: python, opencv, video

I'm new to opencv and I try to generate a video file from a set a jpg pictures.

This works fine if I use ffmpeg : `ffmpeg -y -r 60 -i capture.%d.jpg -c:v libx264 ffmpeg_test.mkv`
With my 120 pictures, this generates a 2s video.
I'd like to do the same with opencv.

Here is the code I use:

```py
import cv2

def record(writer):
  for i in range(121):
    img = cv2.imread(f"capture.{i}.jpg")
    writer.write(img)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'x264')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("py_test.mkv", fourcc, 60.0, [120, 160])
record(writer)
writer.release()
```

I've got no error on execution, the file seems a regular video file, checked with mediainfo, but vlc raise an error (in verbose mode) "mkv error: cannot find any cluster or chapter". The file is 553 bytes.

Ubuntu 22.04
python3-opencv (package from apt)
python 3.10.12 (cv2.**version** = 4.5.4)

I tried changing format (MPEG, mpgv, XVID, mp4v, ...) and container (avi, mp4), the result is always the same (file ~500 bytes).
I concluded that my images are never integrated to the video, but I don't know why.

Comment: Does this help? `ffmpeg -f concat -r 1 -i capture.%d.jpg -r 5 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt fmpeg_test.mkv`

Comment: @toyotaSupra, maybe I was not clear, but the ffmpeg command works fine. I'm trying to obtain the same result using python and cv2.

Comment: OIC. Sorry my mistaken. You're not written pipeline.

Comment: @SebL Does it work if you try as: `writer = cv2.VideoWriter("py_test2.mp4", fourcc, 60, (120, 160))`?

Comment: @VC.One, no, result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in "with shape (120, 160, 3)". while images are 120 height x 160 width, cv2.VideoWriter wants (width, height).

Clue was in [Can't play video created with OpenCV VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000164/cant-play-video-created-with-opencv-videowriter)

After correction, I tried with codec MPEG, mpgv, XVID, mp4v, H264, x264, DIVX, AVI1, RGBA, FLV1, with container mkv. Also with codec XVID, it works with containers mp4 and avi.

I did not try all combinations, but if there is a problem, it is not related to mine.

```
import cv2

def record(writer):
  for i in range(121):
    img = cv2.imread(f"capture.{i}.jpg")
    writer.write(img)

  writer.release()
  
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*'x264')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("py_test.mkv", fourcc, 60.0, [160, 120, 3])
record(writer)
```

Thanks anyone for your time.