# Can not make a video using cv2.VideoWriter.write()

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

```
import cv2
def stich_video(frames):
    output_video_path = 'output_video.avi'
    out_size= (800, 480)
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('XVID'), 24, out_size)
    
    
    for i in frames:
        frame_filename = f"{i}"

        segmented_frame = cv2.imread(segmented_frame_filename)
        # Checking if image is read correctly
        if segmented_frame is None:
            print(f"Error reading frame {i}. Check the file path.")
            continue

        resized_image = cv2.resize(segmented_frame, (800, 480)) 
        # if cv2.imwrite(f"new/{segmented_frame_filename}", image_bgr) is None:
        #     print("error")
        print(resized_image.shape)

        # Write the frame to the output video
        if not out.write(resized_image):
            print(f"Error writing frame {i} to the video.")

    out.release()
```

When I try to writing the image to the video, it gives the error "Error writing frame {i} to the video." What can be the problem here?

I am expecting to create a video with a frames array that contain the names of all the images that are needed to create the video.

Comment: Do you have something like this `while(cap.isOpened()):`?

Comment: @DaimAbbasKazmi See if [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77598195/2057709) has any useful clues for you...